# How many cp14 debug units has a dual-core arm

Tags: debugging, arm, cpu, cpu-registers, processor

If we have a dual-core ARM CPU, does that mean we also have all COprocessors as "dual-cored"?
I mean, do we have two sets of cp14 or cp15 registers in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe each core would have the same debug hw registers IF the maker of the SOC device compiled that silicon IP into each core (which is likely). You'll have to interrogate each core to see if it's supported. Then you'd have to execute the instructions accessing CP14 etc from the core in question (to access its CP14)